# Clean alternatives to passing index by reference

Tags: c#, parsing, indexing, reference, refactoring

In my code I am parsing an array of bytes. To sequentially parse the bytes I am currently passing around the index like so:

```
headerData = ParseHeader(bytes, ref index)
middleData = ParseMiddle(bytes, ref index)
tailData   = ParseTail  (bytes, ref index)
```

Without hardcoding the amount to increment the header, is there a way to achieve similar functionality without having to pass the index by reference? Is this one of the rare cases that using the **ref** keyword is the best solution?

Comment: Use a stream instead.

Comment: [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) is one of examples of how to avoid using indexes at all.

Comment: @SLaks could you give an example of how a stream could be used here?

Comment: Joboman555 I posted an answer based on @SLaks comment ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like SLaks said, a possible solution is to use a stream.

To create a stream from your current bytes array you can do the following:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```

To read the current byte of the stream you can use the `ReadByte` method, shown below:

```
byte b = stream.ReadByte();
```

The stream will keep track of the current index in the array, so your new code would look like:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
headerData = ParseHeader(stream)
middleData = ParseMiddle(stream)
tailData   = ParseTail  (stream)
```

Check out the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) to see other methods that are available for `MemoryStream`.